# How to grey out(disable) all other check box on clicking of one check box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example I am having 4 checkbox.If I click one checkbox all other box has to be grey out(disabled)....

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Show us that you have at least attempted a solution to his problem. you cannot simply expect others to complete your work for you.

Comment: Why don't you use radio buttons if you want to select only 1 option?

Comment: use radio button instead of checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box1" >
<input type="checkbox" name="box2" >
<input type="checkbox" name="box3" >
```

if you want to enable the checkboxes upon unselection, you could use this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().attr('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2WXKY/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This will disable all checkbox when first one is selected. Mostly used in 'check all' in the front-end.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box1" id="gowithit"> All
<input type="checkbox" name="box2" > Red
<input type="checkbox" name="box3" > Blue
<input type="checkbox" name="box4" > Green
```

Javascript:

```
$('#gowithit').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().attr('disabled', this.checked);
});
```